# Filter numeric column containing a digit

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to filter rows of a table where a numeric column contains a digit using maths?

I mean, currently, I'm solving that using:

```sql
where cast(t.numeric_column as varchar(255)) like "%2%"
```

However, I would like to know if could be possible to filter apply numeric operations...

Any ideas?

Comment: The above would likely fail, with the error *"Invalid column name '%2'."*

Comment: Is your `numeric` column always an integer value?

Comment: Why do you require a conversion? Doesn't produce SELECT yourcolumn 
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourcolumn LIKE '%2%' the intended result?

Comment: That would, in fact, implicitly convert the value on the left hand side of the `LIKE`, @JonasMetzler .

Comment: Sure, but why is that a problem? Performance too poor?

Comment: Both conversion and `LIKE` with a leading wild card make the query non-SARGable, and thus result in a scan of the table, @JonasMetzler .

Comment: Evidence that there is an implicit conversion: [Query Plan 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nRs1.png) (with no explicit convert) vs [Query Plan 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMqPp.png) (with explicit convert). Note that the 1st plan has a CONVERT_IMPLICIT instead.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu Just was curious if this performance issue is the reason why the author wanted to avoid that or if this had another background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use division plus the modulus, if you knew the range of possible numbers.  For example, assuming all expected numbers were positive and less than 100,000, you could use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE numeric_column % 10 = 2 OR
      (numeric_column / 10) % 10 = 2 OR
      (numeric_column / 100) % 10 = 2 OR
      (numeric_column / 1000) % 10 = 2 OR
      (numeric_column / 10000) % 10 = 2;
```

Although the above is ugly and unwieldy, it might actually outperform your approach which requires a costly conversion to string.

Comment: Worth noting that this won't work is the `numeric` column contains non-integer values. For example `10.124` won't appear in the results, despite it containing the digit `2`.

Comment: Should your approach work in case: `like "%25%"`, or `like "%56%"`... So, is there any way to get using numeric operations if a numeric value contains another one?

Comment: @Larnu That being said, given that floats are not exact anway, who could say for certain that a 2 were really there.

Comment: One would *assume* that a column called `numeric_column` is a `numeric` rather than a `float`; so hopefully that issue won't arise, @TimBiegeleisen . But them people have columns called "Date` that are an `int` or `varchar`, so it's more *hope* than assumption.